# Extending Knockoutjs objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to extend `KnockoutObservableAny`, besides using what they say in documentation?

```
ko.extenders.logChange = function(target, option) {
    target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       console.log(option + ": " + newValue);
    });
    return target;
};
```

Called by:

```
this.firstName = ko.observable("Bob").extend({logChange: "first name"});
```

I would prefer to call it straight off the object (with intellisense since I am using typescript), but I cannot figure out where to access the constructor in a way I can for `JQuery`.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.foo = function () {
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So then I can call it like `$().foo();`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom functions to any `ko.subscribable` with using the `fn` "pattern" as described in the documentation: [Adding custom functions using "fn"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html)

So you can add your additional function e.g to the `ko.observableArray` with:

```
(function (ko) {
    ko.observableArray.fn.foo = function () {
    //...
    };
})(ko);
```

Or just simply without using the immediately executed function:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.foo = function() {
  //..
}
```